# Redirecting a loggedin user

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am currently using bp-redirect-to-profile plugin and it works exactly how I want it to. However, once the user is loggedin already and say opens the site in a new tab it goes to the home page. I would like it go to the profile page. I am using this code in the header.php and it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. I have this code in the header.php file.

```
<?php  global $bp; ?>

<?php  wp_redirect($bp->loggedin_user->domain); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wp_redirect(get_author_link( true, get_current_user_id()));
```

Comment: @user - if this isn't what you want, can you clarify what you mean by "profile page" ?

Comment: Buddypress has a user profile page. I tried that Evan and I get the following error Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at line 3 header.php. Bp-Redirect-to-profile works but if a already logged in user opens the site up in another tab it goes to the home page which I don't want

Comment: @user2214760 That error means you have some output before the headers were called. Get rid of all `echo` statements or empty space.

Comment: maybe I shouldn't be putting it in headers.php?

Comment: it redirects but i get this error message on top  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testing/wp-includes/deprecated.php:808) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testing/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876

Comment: @Dave you should mark this question as complete and then open up another question with the code that you think is causing the `header` error and we can solve it there.

Comment: Well I think get_current_user_id() is depreciated. I think to do a addfilter but I am not sure how to do it cause that is what the plugin bp-redirect-to-profile does i think i have to find the hook for loggedin user